# How to select row in extjs 3 grid and How to put fiilter

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I created a grid in EXTJS 3. I wanted to selected a row and for that I need to get a checkbox kind of thing at beginning of row. Can please any one help me which config shall I use.
Also how to give filter to columns.
My code is

```
{
xtype: 'grid',
id: 'C_GRID',
height:500,
selType: 'checkboxmodel',
frame: true,
autoHeight: true,
stripeRows: true,
store: myStor,
columns : this.columns,
bbar: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'ABC',
    handler: function() {
       // debugger;
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'XYZ',
    handler: function() {
        //debugger;
    }
}],
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ExtJS 3 version , then you have to give sm config to the grid.

A copy of your code snippet:

```
{
xtype: 'grid',
id: 'C_GRID',
height:500,
sm: new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel({singleSelect:true}),
frame: true,
autoHeight: true,
}
```

You can get the selected row by using :

> Ext.getCmp('C_GRID').getSelectionModel().getSelected();

Comment: thanks !! I am trying this. Can you also help me in filter.

Comment: When I am getting column from xml then I am not getting filter but when I am declaring column in code then I am getting filter.

Comment: checkboxes is not coming.

Comment: NO. I am still in development. I will let you know in some while.

Comment: Thanks This is working. One thing is that I want checkbox thing at very start of row,

Comment: If you do singleSelect:false , it will allow you to do multiple selections.